# Saving a global object to a global array, changing values in object and saving again

Tags: javascript

Trying to capture the time between keyup and keydown as well as between keyup and the keydown of the next keystroke by writing the time and key data to a global object using keys and values and pushing this object to a global array.  The reason for globals is that I don't know how to pass parameters between functions bound to the keydown, keypress and keyup events.  Each event driven function has data I want to save in one object as key value pairs such as the key code and the character typed. Each object represents one keystroke but also contains or uses for calculation some information from the previous keystroke.

By the end the data in each element of the global array seems to be either undefined or the last data entered.

My question is why?

I worked around the problem by eliminating the global object(key values) and replacing it with global variables which change with each keystroke.  Then I was able to create an object in a function (function scope) and push that object in the global array with each new character. It seems to work. Instinctively it feels like it should be the other way around.  I just want to understand why it works this way.  I am a third of the way through the book by Zakas and have a lot more to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking of variables as a box that holds objects. When you do, say `a = b`, then whatever was in `b` is copied to `a`. That is not the way JavaScript works.

Instead, JavaScript works by having an object somewhere, and variables *point to* that object. Then, when you do `a = b`, `a` now points to the same object as `b`; when a property of `b` is modified, the same property of `a` is modified, since the object they point to is the same.

If you want `a = b` to make a copy, you have to do that explicitly. For example, if you have properties `foo` and `bar`, you could do that like this:

```
a = {
    foo: b.foo,
    bar: b.bar
};
```

This only copies down one level, though, so if `b.foo` is an object too, then `a.foo` will be referring to the same object as `b.foo`, and again, modifying any properties of `a.foo` will make the same changes appear on `b.foo`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks icktoofay:  That may explain the problem I was having.  I presume that you are saying that when I was pushing a global object into a global array the global array contained keys and pointers instead of keys and data. When I changed to pushing an object declared in a function into the global array it pushed the object in the form of keys and data instead of pointers that would have gone out of scope when exiting the function. Is that a correct assessment?  I still get some bad data when I cancel the keystroke but that is to be expected and I can just delete that object.

Comment: @user1117975: I think your problem before was you were pushing the same object every time, and since you kept modifying that object, every item in the array appeared to change.